# Bug on flagging functionality

Tags: support, flags

These last days I have noticed that the flagging functionality on SO isn't working on my side, somehow I see that the dialog appear telling me that the flag was cast but when I visit my flagging history the number for moderator attention flags isn't increasing!! In the past I can see that some flags are in queue wainting for others to validate it.

Comment: What's your browser? Can you check whether the request is actually going through to the outside world?

Comment: it's Google Chrome at it's working fine :D, Isould have mention that i can't anymore flag on SO. is it because i had crossed 3k reputation?

Comment: It's not a bug and you can see what happened in the new *votes* tab in your user profile page. You will see all the "flags" you cast as closure votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering you crossed [3k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327899/k-anas?tab=reputation) recently, the flag converts your vote to close flags into close votes.

Also, since you have 3k rep, [you now have Vote To Close privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) & should use them, instead of flagging - though the end result is same.

Comment: Thanks sathya, how I can know the number of helpful flags i have raised?

Comment: it's there [in your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1327899/k-anas), listed under helpful flags. Click on it & you'll get a detailed breakdown @K_Anas

Comment: yes it's there but it doesn't change how can i get the deputy badge than? I'm raising flags voting to close question as duplicate but it doesn't change. is there a way to know i see that we can uses some scripts like for to see how many post you have edited, is there a similar way?

Comment: @K_Anas you shouldn't be flagging _just_ to get a badge, you should be flagging because there's some case which requires a Moderator to come intervene (read: personal info in answers, spam, questions posted as an answer) etc. Start by looking at http://stackoverflow.com/review and review the posts. Number of posts you've edited can be seen in the review section as well

Comment: Lol yes of course, I'm really flagging not constructive Q/A and duplicate ones but I'm feeling like it's not working and that's why I insist on that because many other Highly reputation users flagged same post but raised flags doesn't increase